# How to persist Expo Audio throughout react native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am new to react native. I am trying to make a podcast player. While I was able to make it work in my ***Podcast*** component, when I change to other component, the audio player current status is not recognized.
I am reusing AudioPlayer component (***the one in green***) that is working fine in the Podcast component. But how can I have access to the currently playing song from other pages like Home?

[image: Podcast componet]

This is my AudioPlayer.js that I am trying to reuse in other components. I want to have controls like pause/play, next work from other other components. I am storing the current audio url in redux store but the only thing that I am to do so far is restart the current audio when I click pause from other component.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";
import { audioPlayerAction } from "../actions";
import { radio } from "../assets/radio/radio";
import { styles } from "../assets/styles";
const audio = new Audio.Sound();

const AudioPlayer = (props) => {

  // get currently playing song url from redux store
  const { audioSrc, index } = props.storeState;
  const [currentAudioIndex, setCurrentAudioIndex] = useState(index);
  const [currentAudio, setCurrentAudio] = useState(null);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);
  const [nowPlaying, setNowPlaying] = useState("");
  const [playerStatus, setPlayerStatus] = useState(null);

  Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
    staysActiveInBackground: true,
  });

  // continue playing next song when done
  const onPlaybackStatusUpdate = (playbackStatus) => {
    if (playbackStatus.didJustFinish) {
      next();
    }
  };

  const play = async (url) => {
    if (currentAudio !== url) {
      await audio.unloadAsync();

      try {
        const status = await audio.loadAsync(
          {
            uri: url,
          },
          { shouldPlay: true }
        );

        audio.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(onPlaybackStatusUpdate);

        setCurrentAudio(url);
        setPlayerStatus(status);
        setLoaded(true);
        setPaused(false);
        setNowPlaying(radio[currentAudioIndex].station);
        await audio.playAsync();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    } else if (currentAudio === url && loaded === true && paused === false) {
      await audio.pauseAsync();
      setPaused(true);
    } else if (currentAudio === url && loaded === true && paused === true) {
      await audio.playAsync();
      setPaused(false);
    }
  };

  const next = async () => {
    let nextIndex = index + 1 >= radio.length ? 0 : index + 1;
    setCurrentAudioIndex(nextIndex);
    let nextAudio = radio[nextIndex].url;

    props.audioPlayerAction(nextAudio, true, null, "podcast", nextIndex);
    play(nextAudio);
  };
  const prev = () => {
    let prevSongIndex = index - 1 < 0 ? radio.length - 1 : index - 1;
    let prevAudio = radio[prevSongIndex].url;

    props.audioPlayerAction(prevAudio, true, null, "podcast", prevSongIndex);
    play(prevAudio);
  };
  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
      <View style={style.musicTitle}>
        <Text style={style.musicTitleText}>Now Playing: {nowPlaying}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={style.controls}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => prev()}>
          <AntDesign style={style.icon} name="stepbackward" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => play(audioSrc)}>
          <AntDesign style={style.icon} name={paused ? "play" : "pause"} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => next()}>
          <AntDesign style={style.icon} name="stepforward" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};



const MapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { storeState: state.audioPlayerReducer };
};

export default connect(MapStateToProps, { audioPlayerAction })(AudioPlayer);
```

Comment: Hi @vick.  Did you end up figuring this issue out?  I'm up against the same issue and would love to hear what you discovered.